# how to get an input from user from telegram bot in java?

Tags: java, bots, telegram

i have created a telegram bot and now i need to ask user something , and save the input answer in a string . here i wrote a code : i want if the first command was "/mytext" , this "please enter your text" be showed . and after that , anything that user typed , be saved in a string .
everything is ok but the last part , understanding the second input , doesn't happen !
here is my code of this part :

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    String command = update.getMessage().getText() ;
    long chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
    SendMessage message = new SendMessage() ;

    if (command.equals("/mytext")){
        message.setText("please enter your text");
        String command2 = update.getMessage().getText() ;
        if (command2.equals("hello")){
             message.setText("right");
        }else {
            message.setText("wrong");
        }
    }
    message.setChatId(chatId) ;

    try {
        execute(message);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

please help me with this problem . thanks a lot !

Comment: Where would the user be inputting the string? Is it in the console, or somewhere else

Comment: on the telegram bot

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I assume you are trying to catch multiple inputs/commands from the same Update instance sent by a user which is wrong. Because, each update instance will come with every input/message sent from the user. For example, the first command will be sent as an update, then you will read the command and do whatever you want with it (i.e. store it temporarily in global variable or hashmap in order to get it back for the second upcoming command from the user). After that, for the second command, you should ask the user to send it like this one:

```
message.setText("please enter your text");
message.setChatId(chatId) ;
    try {
        execute(message);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After sending your request of the second command, the user will respond by sending the second command and you are now ready to handle the two commands. The first command can be retrieved from the temporarily global variable and the second one from the last received update.